# Слияния элементов двух контейнеров

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
void SlianyeAndPrint(const list<T> &lst, const list<T> &lst1)
{
    for(auto i = lst.cbegin(); i!=lst.cend(); ++i){
        cout<<*i<<endl; 
    };
}
 
int main()
{
    list<int> Mylist;
    Mylist={1,2,3};
    list<int> Mylist1;
    Mylist1={1,2,3};
    SlianyeAndPrint(Mylist, Mylist1);
    return 0;
}
```

В общем, я пытаюсь сделать слияние двух контейнеров, чтобы у меня Mylist увеличился в размере и туда записались элементы из Mylist1, но не могу понять как это сделать. Контейнер – список. Может есть какие-то встроенные функции в STL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что Вам мешает воспользоваться уже существующим методом [`list::merge()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/merge/), тем более что сам тип списка std-базированный? (Единственное но: перед применением нужно предварительно отсортировать списки при помощи [`list::sort()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/), потому что `merge` работает ТОЛЬКО с отсортированными списками)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    list<int> Mylist;
    Mylist={1,2,3};
    list<int> Mylist1;
    Mylist1={1,2,3};
    Mylist.sort(); Mylist1.sort();
    Mylist.merge(Mylist1);
    for(auto i = Mylist.cbegin(); i!=Mylist.cend(); ++i){
        cout<<*i<<endl; // 1 1 2 2 3 3
    };
    return 0;
}
```

UPD: если же нужно вставить элементы последовательно, то сначала нужно сделать аргумент `&lst` неконстантным — иначе компилятор будет прерывать программу из-за попытки изменить константное значение. Дальше — через [`list::insert()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void SlianyeAndPrint(list<T> &lst, const list<T> &lst1)
{
    for (auto i = lst1.cbegin(); i != lst1.cend(); ++i) {
      lst.insert(lst.cend(), *i);
    }
    for (auto i = lst.cbegin(); i != lst.cend(); ++i){
        cout<<*i<<endl; 
    };
}
 
int main()
{
    list<int> Mylist = {1,2,3};
    list<int> Mylist1 = {1,2,3};
    SlianyeAndPrint(Mylist, Mylist1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению мне сортировка не подходит( Мне нужно, чтобы в итоге было 1 2 3 1 2 3.

Comment: @pane добавил ответ с требуемым результатом. На будущее: постарайтесь сразу описывать вывод, чтобы не нужно было переписывать

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @pane не забудьте отметить данный ответ как верный, если он Вам помог (слева от текста галочка) :)

Answer (score 5):

Если элементы второго списка сохранять не нужно, то оптимальным способом перенести элементы из одного списка в другой является [`std::list<T>::splice`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice):

```
lst.splice(lst.end(), lst1);
```